# Sort Array by Distance for TableView

Tags: ios, xcode

Can someone please help me with sorting my Array by Distance and display that in the TableView?  I have created a property "sortedArray" and synthesized.  I've created  a "sortList" method and called it under didUpdateToLocation.  However it doesn't seem to be sorting the array or I'm not getting the updated results into my TableView.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sortedArray;
-(NSArray *) sortList;
-(NSMutableArray *) barList;
```

---

```
@synthesize sortedArray;
```

---

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    currentLoc = newLocation;

    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 100.0f) {
        [locMgr stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
    NSLog(@"Lat: %f, Long: %f", currentLoc.coordinate.latitude, currentLoc.coordinate.longitude);

    [self barList];
    [self sortList];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


-(NSMutableArray *) barList{
    theauthors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TulsaBars.sqlite"];
        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        }


        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM  TulsaBars";
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }else{

            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                Author * author = [[Author alloc] init];
                author.barName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
                author.barAddress = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
                author.barState = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 5)];
                author.barLat = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 8)];
                author.barLong = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 9)];

                if (currentLoc == nil) {
                    NSLog(@"current location is nil %@", currentLoc);
                }else{

                CLLocation *barLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[author.barLat doubleValue] longitude:[author.barLong doubleValue]];
                CLLocationDistance distancekm = [currentLoc distanceFromLocation: barLocation]/1000;
                NSString *distanceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%f", distancekm];
                author.cachedDist = distanceString;

                [theauthors addObject:author];

                }
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return theauthors;
    }
}


-(NSArray *) sortList{

    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"cachedDist"  ascending:YES];
    sortedArray = [theauthors sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];

    return sortedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Um... your `-sortList` method isn't doing in-place sorting, it's returning a sorted array, which you are throwing away.

<strike>Actually, the same is true for your `-barList` method.</strike>

*Edit:* this wasn't quite true.  `-barList` is in fact repeatedly overwriting an ivar, though it's not clear whether this is intentional.

The upshot of this is that:

```
[self barList];
[self sortList];
```

<strike>does nothing but spin some CPU cycles</strike> - you're not doing anything with their return values!

*Edit:* ok, I see that your sort is (subtly) setting an ivar, but it's confusing because it's also returning a sorted array.  See comments below.

(This also looks like an overly complicated way to sort geodata, but I'm not going to wade through all the code right now.  You need to fix the above before looking at that.)

Comment: My -barList method is how I'm pulling the data from the sql DB and creating my initial array.  I'm trying to sort that array with sortList.  There are only a few lines of code here that are trying to sort.  Please explain why thats complicated or what I should fix.

Comment: @user1454340 I see on closer inspection that you are storing results into an ivar called `theauthors` inside `-barList`.  This confused me because normally such lazy-loading procedures involve a check to see whether you have already populated the ivar and return it directly, which you don't do.  But still `-sortList` is **not sorting in place** - it's returning a sorted array which you are discarding.  There's no reason to think it would affect the table.  Do you see what I'm talking about?

Comment: I think that is what I'm missing.  Am I throwing it away or just not using it? I'm not a big fan of how I've done the -barList.  I'm just trying to get this to work and then go back and clean everything up.  Probably not the best method.

Comment: Argh, I keep getting confused because your methods are written quite strangely.  I see now that `sortedArray` is apparently a backing ivar that you are accessing directly (instead of through its accessor method).  OK, you aren't throwing it away, I was mistaken.  I will take a look at this later and try to sort through it.

Comment: I figured it out.  I have the following line of code in my cellForRowAtIndexPath.
'Author *author = [self.sortedArray objectAtIndex:rowCount];'
It was still using 'theauthors' array.  I forgot to switch it to the new 'sortedArray'